# Creating custom ahref links in PHP

Tags: php

How do you create a custom links in ahref using php as shown below

```
link from : http://www.top10bestwebsitehosting.com/visit.php?site=iPage
goes to : http://www.ipage.com
```

Comment: Please add much more detail and context. What do you mean by "create"? Where are those links at the moment? What are those addresses, are they all running on your server?

Comment: Are you sure this is not mod_rewrite?

Comment: I'm not sure how they did it. You can check out this site. http://www.top10bestwebsitehosting.com .When you point on those links it actually shows a custom link. Then on click goes to the website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like this:

```
$sites = array(
    'iPage'  => 'http://www.ipage.com/',
    'Google' => 'http://www.google.com/',
);

$key = $_GET['site'];

if(isset($sites[$key])) {
    header('Location: ' . $sites[$key]);
    exit;
}

echo 'Sorry, no such site.';
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but how do you insert it into a ahref ?

Comment: `<a href="example.php?site=iPage">go to ipage.com</a>`

Comment: there are errors on this portion if(isset($sites[$key]) { .Could you please fix it?

Comment: Can you turn your brain on, please? No offence but it's just a missing closing parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

There is redirect, if you open in firefox developer tools and after open a link, and pressing escape key(else you will be redirected) you can see the next url:

```
http://naturaltracking.com/redirect.php?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ipage.com%2Fjoin%2Findex.bml%3FAffID%3D638751%26amp%3BLinkName%3D&uid=6344b6a239bb&sid=374eaa4bb6d2&hukc=1&nicid=00004ZQNza&nivkey=FiiRIhiDHa
```

Answer (score 0):

It was most likely done in this way:

1. have an internal list of what `$_GET['site']` can be
2. read `$_GET['site']`
3. redirect to the corresponding website

This is an example:

```
<?php
// visit.php
$pages = array('iPage'=>'www.ipage.com','google','www.google.com');
if (in_array($pages,$_GET['site']))
{
    // do some internal logging or whatever
    header("Location: ".$pages[$_GET['site']]);
}
?>
```

Comment: can I use this to call it ? <a href="example.php?site=iPage">go to ipage.com</a>

Comment: of course you can, why not?

Comment: I think you should use `isset()` instead of `in_array()` because you must check the key not the value

Answer (score 0):

The way top10bestwebsitehosting does is, it keeps the urls in the database. So then it does something similar to the below:

```
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['site']); //check for escapes etc.
$query = mysql_query('select * from `websites` where `name` = {$name} limit 1');
$row = mysql_fetch_row($query);
header('Location: '.$row['url']);
```

Comment: How do you call it in ahref? Please advise.